# Tableview and its contentInset

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a mapView whose size is equal to the screen lying at bottom, and I have a tableView lying on the top of mapview. The effect I want to get is at first I want to see 250 point of height of the map, then, when I scroll the tableView, there is 150 point height for the map. To do this , I set the y of table`s frame to be 150, and the top inset to be 100:

[image]

Now, I can scroll the table up and there is 150 points to be left for the map. But , the main problem I faced for this strategy is that the area below the topInset is still belong to the tableview, so action on that area will move the tableview instead of the mapView.

I think I need advices for:
1. the method to solve the problem I just methioned
2. is my strategy to achieve my purpose effectively? or give me some other way to do this

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how would you solve the issue your way, but one way to solve this is to change the height constraints whenever the tableview is scrolled. You cannot ignore touches on the tableview, and the topInset is a part of the tableview. So although your solution seems more correct, it may not work, leaving the only option of handling tableview scroll.

```
//After setting the tableviewDelegate

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        float difference = self.lastContentOffset.y - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        //Move the top accordingly with some if cases.
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

}
```

Comment: to change the height of the tableView or its y position?

Comment: The height of the map above, and the y position and height of the tableview.

Comment: You will have to handle scroll up and scroll down both.